# Show app icon on iphone lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios8

Is it possible to show my app icon on lock screen in ios8 like camera icon. I'm not asking about "app shortcuts on the Lock screen based on your location".

Answer (score 0):

Not like the camera icon, but if you make use of iBeacons in a physical location and your app is location aware, you can get a small icon in the bottom left of the screen that will allow users to directly view your application.

Check out: http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/06/03/apples-ios-8-uses-ibeacon-tech-brings-location-aware-app-access-to-lock-screen